# Member functions "name" in trait class? (generic adaptor)

Tags: c++, adapter, policy, traits

I have implemented a Policy using the CRTP. The policy requires the `Base` class to have a function called foo:

```
template<typename Base>
struct Policy<Base> {
  // ...
  Base* b(){ return static_cast<Base*>(this); }
  void do(){ b()->foo(); }
};
```

I have one class called `Widget` that uses my policy. `Widget` implements `foo` and everything is fine:

```
struct Widget : Policy<Widget> {
  // ...
  void foo();
};
```

**The problem:** I also have a type called `OldWidget` that implements the functionality of `foo` in a function named `oldFoo`:

```
struct OldWidget : Policy<OldWidget> {
  // ...
  void oldFoo();
};
```

I don't *want* to modify OldWidget (besides extending it with the policy). I don't *want* to use an `AdaptedOldWidget`:

```
struct AdaptedOldWidget : OldWidget, Policy<AdaptedOldWidget> {
  void foo(){ oldFoo(); }
};
```

The best would be to extend my existing `policy_traits` class to something like:

```
template<typename T>
struct policy_traits {};

template<>
struct policy_traits<Widget> {
  // typedefs...
  member_function_name = foo;
};

template<>
struct policy_traits<OldWidget> {
  // typedefs
  member_function_name = oldFoo;
};
```

Such that I can implement the Policy like this:

```
template<typename Base>
struct Policy<Base> {
  // ...
  Base* b() { return static_cast<Base*>(this); }
  void do(){ b()->policy_traits<Base>::member_function_name(); }
};
```

Is there away to achieve something like this in C++?

**Proposed solution**: I could do the following:

```
template<typename Base>
struct Policy<Base> : Policy_Member_Traits<Base> {
  // ...
  Base* b(){ return static_cast<Base*>(this); }
  void do(){ foo_wrapper(); }
};

template<typename T> struct Policy_Member_Traits { };
template<> struct Policy_Member_Traits<Widget> { 
  void foo_wrapper(){ static_cast<T*>(this)->foo(); }
};
template<> struct Policy_Member_Traits<OldWidget> { 
  void foo_wrapper(){ static_cast<T*>(this)->oldFoo(); }
};
```

There must be hopefully a better easier way to achieve this.

Comment: Can't you just specialize the policy for `OldWidget`? (Otherwise, there's an example of a trait that detects the presence of member functions in [the pretty printer code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850473/pretty-print-c-stl-containers).)

Comment: @KerrekSB wouldn't I need to duplicate a lot of the policy code? I would like to reuse everything in the policy, just replace the function name to something dependent on the type. I'll check out the pretty printer code, thanks!

Comment: Just specialize the dispatch (e.g. make another, dedicated "dispatch" policy).

Comment: @KerrekSB like the Policy_Member_Traits policy I just proposed? Isn't there a better way? It's not very clean, and I would need a 1) type_traits class, and 2) a member_function "traits" class, per type... It's just weird.

Comment: Well, in your ill-named `void do()` (keyword alert!), you would say `DispatchPolicy<Base>::dispatch_foo(b);` or something like that, and the `DispatchPolicy` template would only contain the relevant function definitions, specializing individual cases.

Comment: @KerrekSB seems reasonable! keyword indeed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example how specializing selectively. First, some example classes:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
    void foo() const { std::cout << "Foo::foo\n"; }
    void bar() const { std::cout << "Foo::foo\n"; }
};

struct Biz
{
    void old_foo() const { std::cout << "Fiz::old_foo\n"; }
    void bar() const { std::cout << "Fiz::foo\n"; }
};

struct Fiz
{
    void foo() const { std::cout << "Biz::foo\n"; }
    void old_bar() const { std::cout << "Biz::old_foo\n"; }
};
```

Now the trait:

```
template <typename T> struct Dispatch
{
    static void foo(T const & x) { x.foo(); }
    static void bar(T const & x) { x.bar(); }
};

template <> void Dispatch<Biz>::foo(Biz const & x) { x.old_foo(); }
template <> void Dispatch<Fiz>::bar(Fiz const & x) { x.old_bar(); }
```

And here's a usage example:

```
template <typename T> void dispatch(T const & x)
{
    Dispatch<T>::foo(x);
    Dispatch<T>::bar(x);
}

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    Biz b;
    Fiz c;

    dispatch(f);
    dispatch(b);
    dispatch(c);
}
```

Comment: This seems to work! Should I use a reference or a pointer? Im calling dispatch from the CRTP so with the reference is something like `dispatch(*b())` and the objects are pretty large.

Comment: Actually I can include the dispatch in the trait, so I'll mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 3):

first of all: signature of all functions must be the same. then you may set a static member w/ member-function address inside of your `policy_traits`, so you'll be able to call desired function later (from your `Policy` template) using it.

```
typedef void (*void_memfn_type)();

template<>
struct policy_traits<Widget> {
  static void_memfn_type const member_function_name = &Widget::foo;
};

template<>
struct policy_traits<OldWidget> {
  static void_memfn_type const member_function_name = &OldWidget::oldFoo;
};
```

then:

```
template<typename Base>
struct Policy<Base> {
  // ...
  Base* b() { return static_cast<Base*>(this); }
  void do(){ b()->policy_traits<Base>::(*member_function_name)(); }
};
```

Comment: This looks nice but widget is not a complete type until *after* the policy has been instantiated and thus I cannot take a pointer to member function *before* instantiating it. Have you tried this?